# Align NavBar center with width:100%;

Tags: html, css, center, centering, navbar

I know this question has been asked 100 times but i just can't find a thread that helps me. Im trying to center a navigation bar and my div has a width of 100%. I just want my nav bar to be centered. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's my HTML:

```
<! Doctype HTML >
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
    <title>NavBar WareHouse</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav"> <!-- Nav Start -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="tabbed.html">Tabbed</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="tab-colour.html">Colourful</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tab-elegant.html">Elegant</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tab-complex.html">Complex</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="regular.html">Regular</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="reg-colour.html">Colourful</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reg-elegant.html">Elegant</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reg-complex.html">Complex</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="wild.html">Wild</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
/* Main CSS */

html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body{
    background:#e8e8e8;
}
#nav{
    width:100%;
    background: #666;
    height:38px;
    padding:0;
}
#nav ul{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color::#666;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav li{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    width:75px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    background:#666;
}
#nav li:hover{
    background: maroon;
}
#nav a{
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    background: maroon;
}
#nav ul ul{
    display:none;

}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    width:75px;
    text-align: none;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
    top:10px;
}
```

Comment: It's questions like this I want to find a way to work "the center cannot hold it is too late" into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS means that the nav bar actually is being centred but because you're setting every element to the full page width, your nav list item elements are all floating to the left. What proportion of your total page width do you actually want your centred navigation to occupy? Figure that amount out first and adjust the `ul` element accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Firefox 18...

```
#nav ul{
    /*display:inline-block; remove this */
    text-align:center;
    background-color::#666;
    width:400px; /* set this to a static width */
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style: none;
}
```